# Ruby on rails many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models Type and Activity. Type `has_many` activities and Activity `has_many` types. To do this I used the `has_many :through` thing. This is how it looks like

Activity

```
has_many :typeitems
has_many :types, :through => :typeitem
```

Typeitem

```
belongs_to :activity
belongs_to :type
```

Type

```
has_many :typeitems
belongs_to :activity
```

This does not feel right though. I would want to query 2 things

1. Activities of a particular type
2. Types of a particular activity

When I went into rails console and typed `types.activity` I got a nil which means I will get a single object. Should I change the `belongs_to` in Type model to `has_many`.But then it's back to `many-to-many`. There should be a way.

I looked at the docs and found `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I also read this

> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model.

I am not using it now but I might want to in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides need a `has_many :through`:

Activity

```
has_many :typeitems
has_many :types, :through => :typeitem
```

Typeitem

```
belongs_to :activity
belongs_to :type
```

Type

```
has_many :typeitems
has_many :activities, through: :typeitems
```

Comment: how is this different from `has_many` on both sides without a `:through`?